# jQuery - Masonry layout

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-masonry

First time using jquery and im trying to get the basic masonry style to work, i've got the following code in my html...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<head>

<title>_Box</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="masonry.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).ready(function() {
    $("#container").masonry({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          columnWidth: 240,
          isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
        });
});
</script>

<div id="container">

<div class="item"><img src="images/eventbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/forumbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/top10box.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/eventbox.png"></img></div>

</div>

</body>
</head>
```

and the following in my css file...

```
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  width:950px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:100px;
  background-image: url(images/gridbg.png);
}

.item{
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

any help would be great as ive pretty much followed the tutorial yet its not working

this is what it looks like

[image: -]

if it helps, the images are different widths and height.

Question: How do i get the layout to what masonry is supposed to do, that being flow into one another nicely; examples on masonry site.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: please refer to the tinypic, the images are all piled up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `columnWidth`:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $("#container").masonry({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          columnWidth: 240,
          isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
        });
});
```

Also, make sure that you have properly included both `jQuery` script and the `masonry.js` script.

And add the following **CSS** to your code:

```
.item{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Doing that gives me the following: http://tinypic.com/r/2vn120o/6 which is still incorrect - the scripts are both properly included aswell

Comment: i've now got http://i47.tinypic.com/2jfdr7n.png though i want the 3rd box on the 2nd row to fill that gap? any way i can do this.

Comment: I'm not sure - not to be rude I think I've answered the original question. If you want, open up a second question and post a lot more `html` and `css` and you'll get even more answers. This is all I can give with the given information

Comment: @bok The problem is because the bottom two div's are wider than the top div on the top left. They need to amount to the same width. The code I gave you is correct.

Comment: widths have been resized yet the problem is still occuring

Comment: @box I really can't do anything more than guess from where I'm sitting - A new question with the up to date code and the *new* issue should be opened.